# Subcaption defaulting to capital letter labels?

Tags: captions, subcaption, amsart

I seem to be having a unique problem. There are many questions asking about how to change subcaption to a label with capital letters but for me my program is defaulting to capital letters when I would prefer lowercase.

My preamble

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\setlength\parindent{0pt} %no auto indentation for new paragraphs
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{a4paper} 
\usepackage{natbib}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, calc, dsfont}   
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{subcaption, caption, graphicx} %figure packages
\usepackage{authblk} %author affiliations
\usepackage{setspace, lineno} %double spaced etc. options, line numbering

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,chains,automata,positioning}
```

My figure

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[]{0.48\textwidth}
          \includegraphics{Figure1.pdf}
          \caption{}
          \label{FigPractice} 
  \end{subfigure}

  \begin{subfigure}[]{0.48\textwidth}
          \includegraphics{Figure2.pdf}
          \caption{}
          \label{PracticeAge}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{a caption}
\end{figure}
```

I've also tried `\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `amsart` default uses small caps for the labels. What you see aren't actually uppercase letters, but lowercase small caps. The picture displays it nicely, i changed the the appearance of the second subfigure to be uppercase (`Alph`). The word figure reveals it quite nice as well.

[image: mhhAmsartSubcaptionlabel.]

You can use `captionsetup` to set the font of the label. You can restrict it to subfigures, using the optional argument.

[image: mhhAmsartCaptionsetup]

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelfont=rm}
%\captionsetup{labelfont=rm}
\begin{document}\begin{figure}[h!]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[]{0.48\textwidth}
        \caption{A}
        \label{FigPractice} 
    \end{subfigure}\par
    \renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\Alph{subfigure}}
    \begin{subfigure}[]{0.48\textwidth}
        \caption{B}
        \label{PracticeAge}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{a caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The AMS-classes define documents in the style of the AMS. I wouldn't call that messing around. If you sell designer lamps, and use a hammer for reshaping, would you say the designer lamp is messing with the way a lamp is supposed to look like?

Comment: adding \captionsetup[subfigure]{margin=0pt, parskip=0pt, hangindent=0pt, indention=0pt,  labelformat=parens, labelfont=rm} (the default settings for subcaption) worked for me.